# Wordpress Debugging does not work

Tags: php, wordpress, debugging

currently I'm trying to get into Wordpress debugging.

I read the Wordpress debugging manual, I found here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress

I enabled debugging in my wp-config.php

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG',         true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG',     true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true );
define( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG',     true );
define( 'SAVEQUERIES',      true );
```

But I have not output. The /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/ does not contain the debug.log file. And yes, the directory is writable to the Webserver. And even if I create the file by my own, there is no output to the file. Even with 777 rights. There is also no error output in the Webservers Log File. And yes, the wp-config.php file is the right one, because if I have an (syntax) error in this file, php gives me the error message.

For the installation I used a clean installed machine with a clean Wordpress installation. First of all, I was trying with nginx+php-fpm without any success, but then I also tried apache with mod-php7.0. Same result, no output to the debug.log.

So what can I do or what can I try?

Answer (score 2):

Try this format instead in your wp-config.php file.

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);

if ( WP_DEBUG ) {
    // Enable Debug logging to the /wp-content/debug.log file
    define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
    define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
    @ini_set( 'log_errors', 'On' );
    @ini_set( 'display_errors', 'Off' );
    @ini_set( 'error_reporting', E_ALL );
    @ini_set( 'error_log', 'php_error.log' );
    define('SAVEQUERIES', false); // show queries
    define( 'WCS_DEBUG', true ); // show scheduled jobs for WooCommerce under Tools menu
}
```

Comment: Is PHP sensitive about spaces? `define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );` has a space before `( 'WP...` and after `true );` where as `define('SAVEQUERIES', false);` doesn't.

Comment: It doesn't matter about spaces, I add space as a personal preference.

Comment: Try using plugins such as Issues Tracker or similar to control the WP_DEBUG, WP_DEBUG_LOG, WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY, SCRIPT_DEBUG constants and view logs